# Inflate a TableRow and ad to existing table

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, tablerow

I want to add a dynamic number of rows to a `TableLayout`. My original code defined the table in the `.axml` file and all of the 32 rows. The rows themselves were fairly complex with an `ImageView` and then another embedded table layout.

I was then asked to add another 10 rows to the table and I thought there must be a better way rather than having 42 identically laid out table rows all in `.axml` and looked at making it more data driven so i could extend the table at a later date if needed.

My initial thought was to create a `.axml` file with just the `TableRow` definition and then in code loop through my data and inflate the row from the `.axml` and add to the view.  My problem seems to be with the `.axml` file itself.  The start of my file is

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">
        
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivSign"
            android:src="@drawable/sign_menatwork"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="72dp"
            android:contentDescription="Men at Work" />
```

However this does not work as the compiler fails to compile it (no error just says failed to compile).  I added a `LinearLayout` around the `TableRow` but this did not help.

Can I define the `TableRow` in this way or would I be best converting to a `Grid`?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to add a dynamic number of rows to a TableLayout.

Adding TableRow in TableLayout dynamiclly, you can take a look:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:id="@+id/tableLayout1" 
android:stretchColumns="*">
</TableLayout>

TableLayout tablelayout1;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
        tablelayout1 = FindViewById<TableLayout>(Resource.Id.tableLayout1);
        tablerow();
    }

    void  tablerow()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            TableLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MatchParent, LayoutParams.WrapContent);
            TableRow.LayoutParams layoutParams2 = new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MatchParent, LayoutParams.WrapContent);

            TextView date = new TextView(this);

            //Use TableRow
            date.LayoutParameters = layoutParams2;

            date.SetBackgroundColor(Color.ParseColor("#FFFFC0"));
            date.SetTextSize(Android.Util.ComplexUnitType.Px, (float)30.0);
            date.SetTextColor(Color.Black);
            date.Text = "date";
            date.SetPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);

            TextView name = new TextView(this);

            //Use TableRow
            name.LayoutParameters = layoutParams2;

            name.SetBackgroundColor(Color.ParseColor("#FFFFC0"));
            name.SetTextColor(Color.Black);
            name.SetTextSize(Android.Util.ComplexUnitType.Px, (float)30.0);
            name.Text = "title";
            name.SetPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);

            //Use TableLayout
            tr.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;
          
            tr.AddView(date);
            tr.AddView(name);
            tablelayout1.AddView(tr, i);
        }
    }
```

**Update:**

First, create new layout.xml, just only TableRow.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:text="Open..."
        android:padding="3dip"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Ctrl-O"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:padding="3dip"/>
</TableRow>
```

Then Inflating the TableRow.

```
 void  tablerow()
    {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)GetSystemService(LayoutInflaterService);
       
        TableRow tableRow = (TableRow)layoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.layout1, null);
      
        tablelayout1.AddView(tableRow);
       
    }

 TableLayout tablelayout1;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
        tablelayout1 = FindViewById<TableLayout>(Resource.Id.tableLayout1);
        tablerow();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks - I have something pretty similar already but as my TableRow has in itself a fairly complex structure I was wanting to define the TableRow in a .axml file and then Inflate the .axml for each row and add to the table.

It seems that you cannot define a single TableRow within a .axml file and then inflate it as a view - the .axml throws errors as above

Comment: @user1169502 You mean that you just want to add TableRow in a .xml file, no other controls, then add this .xml file in TableLayout by code behind?

Comment: Exactly - I don't know how many table rows I need but the format of the table row is the same for all rows but quite complex.  Just makes sense to have the TableRow in a .axml file and then inflate each row before adding to the table.

Comment: @user1169502 I find one way to do this, please take a look my update.